# Angular service always undefined when calling in async validator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I already looked up a lot of other SO questions but none of them worked.

I'm trying to create an async validator which checks if an entered username is already existing. But whenever I enter a letter into the input field I get an error that my `userService` instance is `undefined`.

Following is my `UserService`:

```
export interface UsernameCheck {
  info: string,
  usernameAvailable: boolean;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5001/project-f-angular/us-central1';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  checkUsername(username: string) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('username', username);

    return this.http.get<UsernameCheck>(`${this.apiUrl}/checkUsername`, {params});
  }
}
```

The http request is pointing to a locally running Firebase Cloud Functions emulator.

This is my component in which I'm using it:

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
  signUpForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: [null, Validators.required, this.existingUsername],
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: [null, Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  existingUsername(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    console.log(control.value);
    return this.userService.checkUsername(control.value)
      .pipe(
        map(res => {
          return res.usernameAvailable ? null : {existingUsername: true};
        })
      );
  }
}
```

This is the error I get after entering the first letter into the input field:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'userService' of undefined
    at existingUsername (sign-up.component.ts:45)
    at forms.js:1492
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeAsyncValidators (forms.js:1488)
    at FormControl.asyncValidator (forms.js:1446)
    at FormControl._runAsyncValidator (forms.js:4100)
    at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:4053)
    at FormControl.setValue (forms.js:4692)
    at updateControl (forms.js:3299)
    at DefaultValueAccessor.onChange (forms.js:3271)
```

I also added my Service to `app.module.ts` under `providers`.

If I subscribe to my `userService` inside `ngOnInit` my method works like desired and returns the right response.

I'm new to reactive forms and the validators stuff.

So, does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If validator method is in the same class then bind to this, and if its in different class then simply pass the service instance as a param. Check this https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `bind` to `this` in order to pass the right context to the validator.

```js
this.signUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   username: [null, Validators.required, this.existingUsername.bind(this)],  // <--
   email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
   password: [null, Validators.required],
   confirmPassword: [null, Validators.required]
});
```

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yshhqd) example demonstrating the solution.

Hope this helps.